# ¿Como eliminar una columna con pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

estoy intentando eliminar varias columnas de un fichero CSV pero no quiero utilizar las etiquetas o nombres de las columnas. En concreto quiero eliminar las columnas 0,1 y 2 del dataframe.

El código que escribo es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
df = 'C:/Users/BK12039/OneDrive - Bankinter/9763. Común/D. Datos/3. Bancos 
Centrales/1.España/be04/be0402.csv'
dfa = pd.read_csv(df, encoding='latin-1', sep = ';').drop(df.columns[[0, 
1, 2]], axis= 1)
print (fichero_0402a)
```

Pero da el siguiente error y no logro ver qué estoy haciendo mal: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'

¿Podríais ayudarme? Gracias

Comment: estoy probando con varios ficheros csv con distintos nombre y nada, no funciona, me da el mismo error siempre

Comment: cogí un archivo csv ubicado en la carpeta de descargas, por lo que no tienen ningun caracter especial

Comment: Estas haciendo `df.columns` pero `df` es un string. La forma correcta de hacerlo sería `dfa = pd.read_csv(df, encoding='latin-1', sep = ';').drop([0, 
1, 2], axis= 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mejor importar y modificar en diferentes pasos para evitar errors.

```
import pandas as pd

archivo = "./datos.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(archivo)

#    col1  col2  col3  col4
# 0     6     3     2     7
# 1     6     6     5     5
# 2     2     8     9     4
# 3     9     3     5     5
...



df = df.drop( 
    df.iloc[:,0:2].columns,
    axis=1
)

#    col3  col4
# 0     2     7
# 1     5     5
# 2     9     4
# 3     5     5
...
```

Y date cuenta de que usar números para las columas parece producir error:

```
df = df.drop( 
    [0,1,2],
    axis=1
)
```

produce:

```
KeyError: '[0 1 2] not found in axis'
```

Por eso aislar los nombres de las columnas es necesario:

```
df.iloc[:,0:2].columns
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Ahora si me funciona bien

Comment: ¡Por nada! @Bea